# Accepting multiple phone numbers in the textfield

Tags: regex

I Need a regular expression which should accept

1. multiple phone numbers  at least 3
2. '+', ' ', '-' these 3 special characters are optional. The field should should   accept if those special characters are given or not in the field

EX: +91 1234567890, 123 456 7890, 123-456-789 It should accept all these formats and the field should accept at least 3 phone numbers.

Can anyone please suggest a best solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 1. Which language?. 2. WHat about +91 123-456-789?

Comment: 1. English     2. It should accept Indain numbers as well as US numbers   3. I tried with this solution /^\\+\\d{8,15}(,\\s\\+\\d{8,15})*$/  - in which + is mandatory while giving the phone numbers and spaces are not allowing. I want + and whites paces  as optional.

Comment: see answer below. mark it as the answer if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a regular expression you can use.

```
((\+?\s?([0-9]{1,4}|[1](?:-?)[0-9]{3}(?:-?))(?:\s?)*)?([(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?)(?:\s*-?\s*)([0-9]{3})(?:\s*-?\s*)([0-9]{4}))
```

[RegexStorm Validation Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%5c%2b%3f%5cs%3f(%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c4%7d%7c%5b1%5d(%3f%3a-%3f)%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d(%3f%3a-%3f))(%3f%3a%5cs%3f)*)%3f(%5b(%5d%3f%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d%5b)%5d%3f)(%3f%3a%5cs*-%3f%5cs*)(%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d)(%3f%3a%5cs*-%3f%5cs*)(%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d))&i=%2b1+(815)+560+-+1911%0d%0a%2b1+(630)5601911%0d%0a%2b91+1234567890%0d%0a123+456+7890%0d%0a123-456-7894%0d%0a%2b1-268+(123)+456-7894)

[Regex101 Validation and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/sU7kB6/2)